# Double cannot append to an AnyObject array?

Tags: swift

I tried to append an Double type variable `operand` in to an array of AnyObject.

```
private var internalProgram = [AnyObject]()
internalProgram.append(operand)
```

However, it was shown that `Argument type 'Double' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'`. Must I cast the `operand` as `AnyObject`?

Answer (score 0):

```
let numberOperand = NSNumber(double: operand)
yourArrayOfAnyObject.append(numberOperand)
```